# Why in safari div inside box with scroll on overflow-y collapsing?

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

I have a box with `overflow-y: scroll` and inside many divs.
Each div has a `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` and this distance works well but not only for `safari`

```css
#father-scroll {
  width: 150px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="father-scroll">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Now i show two images of my project (the first with firefox desktop and the second is safari on iphone)

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**

I have created a jsfiddle with a copy of my project.
https://jsfiddle.net/1c7ts6yj/

Comment: First of all, try to use `margin` only in one direction (either `top` or `bottom`) in order to avoid margin-collapsing.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing

Comment: @Konrud yes in my project i use only one margin but nothing...that is not the problem

Comment: Your example code works fine in iOS Safari, and looks nothing like your screenshots. Please create a [MRE].

Comment: @Turnip i edited my poste with a jsfiddle of reproducible example

Comment: @Turnip jsfiddle is not responsive but if you can open it with an apple you can see the problem (not change client with firebug because in that case works)

Comment: Did you try setting `height: 36px;` rather then `min-height` just to test

Comment: @Awais again not works..

Comment: @Borja I am sure its height issue just set that to `auto` or `100px` or use `flex` on that item